# Let $X$ be an infinite set. Show that $\tau={\{\emptyset}\}\cup\{A:A^c\text{ is finite}\}$ is a topology on $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Problem: Let $X$  be an infinite set. Show that $\tau={\{\emptyset}\}\cup\{A:A^c\text{ is finite}\}$ is a topology on $X$.
 I know I have to satisfy the following conditions:

1. empty set and $X$ are members of $\tau$.
2. Each union of members of $\tau$ is also in $\tau$.
3. Each finite intersection of members of $\tau$ is also a member of $\tau$.

Now, is it possible to get empty set to be a member in $\tau$ base on the definition? Also $X$? How to show the conditions 2 and 3. I am really confused since our Professor gave example which finite such as $\{1,2,3,4\}$ only.. Please help me on this..

Comment: BTW it is called [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinite_topology) or finite complement topology.

Comment: You have explicitly included empty set $\emptyset$ in $\tau$ by your definition.  The other sets in $\tau$ are "cofinite", i.e. they have a complement which is finite.  But here the empty set $\emptyset$ has complement $X$, which is infinite.  That is why it is necessary to treat the open set $\emptyset$ in the topology $\tau$ differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $X \in \tau$ since $X^c = \emptyset$ is finite.
Also, $\emptyset \in\tau$ by definition ($0$ is another notation for $\emptyset$).

Now suppose $U_i \in \tau$ for all $i \in I$. That means some of them are empty and some of them have a finite complement. If they are all empty, then their union is also empty and is open by definition. If not, consider $$\left( \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i \right)^c = \bigcap_{i \in I} U_i^c.$$ This set is finite since at least one $U_i^c$ is. I let you do the same with the finite intersection.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir..Topology by DUgundji is our textbook..Our Professor gets problems from the exercises of the text for our exams and sad to say it does not have any solutions which guides me to my answer if it is correct. I really find it hard.Any suggestions PLEASE!!!